# How is it possible anchor element is not able to press?

Tags: html, css

Press links in footer is not possible why? https://tikex-dev.com/

I can not replicate this loading code into snippet editor.

Though `cursor: pointer` is set for each link, the hand icon does not appear when cursor is over `<a>`.

[image]

Even if I remove all the elements and keep only `footer`, same phenomenon happend. Could `position: fixed;` has such a side effect?

```
.footer-parallax {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -121;
}
```

I checked this: [onclick event not working with position:fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794598/onclick-event-not-working-with-positionfixed)

If I remove `main` then `footer`'s link are clickable. But of course I need `main`. `main` has a margin-bottom, which makes footer visible. Unfortunatelly `margin-bottom` swallows the event sent to footer. I do not get why in the tutorial page I am following not happens the same: http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/

Comment: `overflow: overlay;` in `body, html` seems to be preventing it from working. Note that your question is required to have a [mcve] and that you can't just point to the site having problems. Otherwise once the issue is resolved, this question will have no value to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it, hope it helps

```
<div class="outer-content">
    <div class="main-content">
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
      <p>A jelen Általános Szerződési Feltételek (a továbbiakban: ÁSZF) határozza meg a Szolgáltató, valamint az
        internetes rendszerét használó természetes vagy jogi személy (a továbbiakban: Vásárló) között belépőjegyek,
        bérletek és voucherek, valamint megtekintési/letöltési jogosultságok (a továbbiakban: Belépőjegyek)
        megvásárlására vonatkozó szolgáltatás igénybevételének feltételeit, valamint a Szolgáltató, a rendezvény
        szervezője és a Vásárló között keletkező jogokat és kötelezettségeket.</p>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer" id="footer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperSandip/gyaf2ev3/3/" title="" target="_blank">jsfiddle.net/DeveloperSandip</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

```
.main-content{ margin-bottom: 180px; }
.main-content p{ margin: 0 0 30px 0; }

.footer{ height: 150px;  position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; z-index: 2; width: 100%; background-color: #000; }
.footer ul li{ color: #fff; margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
.footer ul a{ color: #fff; }
```

Or check in jsfiddle example link :

https://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperSandip/gyaf2ev3/6/